# Is it possible to have a cron job run more frequently than once every minute?

Tags: centos, cron

CentOS 6

I have a shell script that performs a task every minute.  The task itself only takes a couple seconds to complete and ideally I'd like to have this shell script execute 2-3 times per minute.  Is that possible to do with cron?  Or is the fastest interval once every 60 seconds?

Comment: have you tried , which posted ?

Answer (score 8):

`cron`'s manpage says that

> cron(8) examines cron entries once every minute.

so its resolution is 60 seconds by design.  You could have a cron job that calls the script more than once, but you'll have to be careful that the jobs don't start overlapping each other in case the script takes longer than expected.

If you really need (say) execution every 30 seconds, you'd be better off wrapping your script in a loop and daemonising it.  You'll have to write your own error handling, as you won't be able to rely on `cron` emailing you errors any more.

Answer (score 8):

Just an add-on for [Rahul Patil](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/28434/rahul-patil) answer.
Using his answer, I have achieved the required result the following way:

```
* * * * *  /path/of/myscript.sh
* * * * *  sleep 20s && /path/of/myscript.sh
* * * * *  sleep 40s && /path/of/myscript.sh
```

This allowed me to execute the script 3 times per minute.

Answer (score 6):

It's simple just use below syntax in cron

it will run if first run successfully then other and so on

```
* * * * *  /path/of/yoursript.sh && sleep 5s && /path/of/yoursript.sh && sleep 5s && /path/of/yoursript.sh
```